# Aggregate non-numerical data Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one (large) pandas dataframe filled with either 0's or some strings. We can assume the below example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 'cc'], 'B': ['aa', 0, 0], 'C': [0, 'bb', 0]})
```

Is there a fast way to create a new dataframe with same index as the initial one and that will get all the non-numerical values for each row? There should be only one non-numerical data per row.

Desired output in this example would be:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Result': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']})
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First replace all non numeric values to empty strings and then use `sum` if there is only one non missing value:

```
s = df.where(df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isna(), '').sum(axis=1)
print (s)
0    aa
1    bb
2    cc
dtype: object
```

Another generalize solution if multiple values and need some separator like `,` - then is really fast using list comprehension and test for non integers or non floats values with `join`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 'cc'], 'B': ['aa', 0, 0], 'C': [0, 'bb', 'kk']})

L = [','.join(y for y in x if not isinstance(y, (float, int))) for x in df.to_numpy()]
s = pd.Series(L, index=df.index)
print (s)
0       aa
1       bb
2    cc,kk
dtype: object
```

Comment: brilliant! And thanks for the case where we may have multiple strings. Very helpful

Answer (score 2):

> ### Pandas DataFrame filled with either 0's or some strings.

You can replace `0`s with empty string i.e `''` using [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) then use [`df.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)

```
df.replace(0, '').sum(axis=1)

0    aa
1    bb
2    cc
dtype: object
```

If you want more generalized solution take a look at [jezrael's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63448076/12416453) which replaces every numeric value.

Here's a generalized solution with `df.replace`

```
df.astype(str).replace(regex='\d+', value='').sum(axis=1)
```